# What do I need to update a late 2012, 27" iMac to SSD?

Tags: imac, ssd

I know I need this [thermal sensor from OWC](https://owcshop.eu/catalog/product_info.php/upgrade-imacs-2012-later-tools-p-1256).

I want a 2TB SSD disk. My question is: will any SSD disk fit inside a late 2012 iMac?

Do I need any special frame to make it fit?

I will be replacing the internal HD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not "any" SSD: SSDs come in a wide range of shapes and connectors. But any SATA 2.5" drive (in the same old form factor as Hard Drives) should work.

The tear-down instructions are found in [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+27-Inch+EMC+2546+Hard+Drive+Replacement/15796). It is marked as "difficult". If it looks risky, you may want to just use an external SSD, connected by Thunderbolt, which should be sufficiently fast.

Comment: I did this with a new Mac Mini, got the less expensive one with the smaller SSD and plugged in an external 1TB drive VIA USB-C/Thunderbolt for my user folder. Works a treat.